# How to convert a python dict to a string with "beautified" dict formatting?

Tags: python

I want to convert my python dict into a string preserving its "dict like" formatting i.e. spaces and \n.

Input:

```
myDict = {
    "params": {
                "someValue": {
                    "in": "hello",
                    "value": "visible",
                    "required": "true"
                }
            }
}
```

Required Output(String) that prints in the exact below format:

```
myStr = '"params": {
                "someValue": {
                    "in": "hello",
                    "value": "visible",
                    "required": "true"
                }
            }'
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't get your query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you aware of the json module? Beacause it looks like you have JSON on your hands...

Comment: The formatting you show is unpredictable (i.e., inconsistent). Is that intentional?

Comment: Actually, that dict is loaded from a JSON file using json.load()

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am new to using python for file processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps` accepts an `indent` parameter to pretty print the dict with desired indentation:

```
import json
json.dumps(myDict, indent=4)
#Output:
'{\n    "params": {\n        "someValue": {\n            "in": "hello",\n            "value": "visible",\n            "required": "true"\n        }\n    }\n}'
```

Comment: The OP's desired output isn't even valid JSON. It's a raw key/value pair.